# Golang Map with array of values

Tags: go

What does this statement mean in Go:

```
Student.bookMap=map[string][]*model.Books{}
```

Where `Student` is:

```
type Student struct{
    bookMap map[string][]*model.Books
}
```

and we have a model package

```
package model

type Books struct {
    bookName   string  `db:"Name"`
    bookAuthor string  `db:"Author"`
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That statement is initializing the map `Student.bookMap` to an empty map (which has the following structure: key -> `string`, value -> slice of pointers of `model.Books`).

Answer (score 0):

It means the member `bookMap` of a `struct` `Student` contains a `map` which takes a `string` as a *key*, and an array (slice) of pointers to instances of `model.Books` as *value*.